# vb.net how to get Select @@Identity

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

i have this code [Sample 1] and it is working. 
It show me ID for actual inserted data from Access, but I would like to use something like in [Sample 2], but i still don't know find out how to write right code for that. :(

Sample 1 [working]

```
        Dim query As String = "Insert Into REGISTER (DC,Price) Values (?,?)"
    Dim FindID As String = "Select @@Identity"
    Dim ID As Integer
    Dim connect As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\sourcepath\db.accdb"
    Using conn As New OleDbConnection(connect)
        Using cmd As New OleDbCommand(query, conn)
            conn.Open()
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("", Format(Now, "yy") & Format(DatePart(DateInterval.WeekOfYear, Now), "00"))
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("", PriceTextBox.Text)
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            cmd.CommandText = FindID
            ID = cmd.ExecuteScalar()
            conn.Close()
        End Using
    End Using
```

Sample 2 [here I need help]
This code write data to Access but I can't get the ID.
(Part for get ID isn't in code)

```
    Dim rw As DataRow
    rw = RegisterDBDataSet.REGISTER.NewRow
    rw.Item("Price") = Format(Now, "dd.MM.yyyy")
    rw.Item("DC") = Format(DatePart(DateInterval.WeekOfYear, Now), "00"))

    Try
        RegisterDBDataSet.REGISTER.Rows.Add(rw)
        REGISTERTableAdapter.Update(RegisterDBDataSet.REGISTER)
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try
```

what must i put into code for get ID in sample 2?
thanks

Comment: Here is a working project using a mdb but works no different with accdb. The query for obtaining the new primary key is setup no different than default select statement. Shows a parent child relationship also but will work with just one table. https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=A3D5A9A9A28080D1!489&authkey=!APu_AF5Vf7vU6v8&ithint=file%2czip

Answer (score 1):

You should add an handler for the RowUpdated event of the OleDbDataAdapter, then in this handler execute your command to retrieve the Identity value generated by your query

```
  RegisterDBDataSet.REGISTER.Rows.Add(rw)
  AddHandler REGISTERTableAdapter.RowUpdated, AddressOf(rowUpdateEvent)
  REGISTERTableAdapter.Update(RegisterDBDataSet.REGISTER)

  .....

  Sub rowUpdateEvent(sender As Object , args As OleDbRowUpdatedEventArgs)
       Dim identity = "SELECT @@IDENTITY"
       Dim cmd = New OleDbCommand(identity, args.Command.Connection)
       ID = cmd.ExecuteScalar()
  End Sub
```

Of course that ID variable is global to your form code